# label overlap with formula

Tags: pdftex, labels

When I compile a formula with following code:

```
\begin{eqnarray}\label{eq:derivativeES}
\dot{c}_k(t_j) &=& \frac{\dot{c}_k( t_{j+1})-\dot{c}_k(t_j)}{\triangle t},1\le j\le n-1,1\le k\le K
\end{eqnarray}
```

I get the following result [image]

How to handle this type of problem ,as we can see formula overlap with label

Comment: avoid eqnarray and use align from amsmath instead. The amsmath alignments move the equation number if necessary (eqnarray should be avoided in general, not just in this case)

Comment: thank you I found a similar post here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48617/189902